# Image of a non-convergent sequence under a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis

Can the image of a non-convergent sequence of points on the real line under a continuous map be convergent? Under a smooth map?

**Remark:** I exclude sequences that diverge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (which may be regarded as sequences converging to $\infty$ or $-\infty$); for such sequences, the answer is in the affirmative.

Example: The image of the sequence $\{1,2,3,...\}$ under the mapping $x \mapsto 1/x$.

I also exclude the trivial example of the zero map.

Comment: Yes, you can always construct examples : continuity only says that convergent sequences map to convergent ones , while placing no restriction on non-convergent sequences. So a non-convergent sequence could very well map to a convergent one : take a periodic function (like $\sin$) and find a sequence diverging to infinity whose image is just one point, hence a convergent sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.

Comment: Actually, I did exclude sequences diverging to infinity in my post (see my Remark).

Comment: doesn't make a difference : for $\sin x$ take the sequence $0,\pi,0,\pi,...$, then the same holds. For a non-trivial example, take $f(x) = 2x^2+7$ and take the sequence $(-1)^n(1+\frac 1n)$. I mean, you can make it up as you go! (+1 for question ,I like it)

Answer (score 2):

For non constant (not just non zero function)

$$x_n=(-1)^n \quad \text{and} \quad f(x)=|x|$$

You don't even need continuity I shall say. For example,

$$f(x)=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$$

with the same sequence is another example, where in addition $f$ is **nowhere** continuous!

Comment: Right! Thank you.